# How to change problem parameter in cvxpy without recompiling?

Tags: cvxpy, mosek

I have a SDP problem that takes a couple MOSEK solver seconds to run but a couple minutes to compile in cvxpy. I hope to be able to change parameters and solve again without having to recompile, and see what form it's compiled into, so that I can directly call MOSEK next time. Putting the same problem into MOSEK fusion also takes a few minutes to compile, so it's definitely not the most efficient formulation.

Is there a way to rerun cvxpy without recompiling a problem, or find the mosek.task it created?

Output:

```
Total num constraints: 3070
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.4.1                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: Your problem has 1764 variables, 3070 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: Your problem is compiled with the CPP canonicalization backend.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=MOSEK).
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> MOSEK
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:10 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:11 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:28:11 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:26 PM: Applying reduction MOSEK
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:34 PM: Finished problem compilation (took 1.436e+02 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:34 PM: Invoking solver MOSEK  to obtain a solution.


(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM: Problem
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Name                   :                 
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Objective sense        : maximize        
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Type                   : CONIC (conic optimization problem)
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Constraints            : 903             
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Affine conic cons.     : 0               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Disjunctive cons.      : 0               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Cones                  : 0               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Scalar variables       : 3069            
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Matrix variables       : 1 (scalarized: 903)
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM:   Integer variables      : 0               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM: 
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:37 PM: Optimizer started.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:38 PM: Presolve started.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:38 PM: Linear dependency checker started.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:38 PM: Linear dependency checker terminated.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:38 PM: Eliminator started.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Freed constraints in eliminator : 0
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Eliminator terminated.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Eliminator - tries                  : 1                 time                   : 0.00            
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Lin. dep.  - tries                  : 1                 time                   : 0.05            
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Lin. dep.  - primal attempts        : 1                 successes              : 1               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Lin. dep.  - dual attempts          : 0                 successes              : 0               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Lin. dep.  - primal deps.           : 0                 dual deps.             : 0               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:39 PM: Presolve terminated. Time: 1.40    
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: GP based matrix reordering started.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: GP based matrix reordering terminated.
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Optimizer  - threads                : 16              
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Optimizer  - solved problem         : the primal      
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Optimizer  - Constraints            : 903             
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Optimizer  - Cones                  : 1               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Optimizer  - Scalar variables       : 2977              conic                  : 2               
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Optimizer  - Semi-definite variables: 1                 scalarized             : 903             
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Factor     - setup time             : 0.42            
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Factor     - dense det. time        : 0.09              GP order time          : 0.01            
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Factor     - nonzeros before factor : 4.08e+05          after factor           : 4.08e+05        
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Factor     - dense dim.             : 0                 flops                  : 2.00e+09        
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: Factor     - GP saved nzs           : 0                 GP saved flops         : 1.68e+09        
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: ITE PFEAS    DFEAS    GFEAS    PRSTATUS   POBJ              DOBJ              MU       TIME  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: 0   1.0e+00  1.0e+00  1.0e+00  0.00e+00   -0.000000000e+00  -0.000000000e+00  1.0e+00  3.28  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:40 PM: 1   9.5e-02  9.5e-02  2.2e-02  1.56e+00   1.400359896e-01   1.569570400e-01   9.5e-02  3.68  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:41 PM: 2   2.7e-03  2.7e-03  2.4e-04  8.33e-01   1.203192748e-01   1.152889102e-01   2.7e-03  4.12  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:41 PM: 3   2.9e-04  2.9e-04  2.4e-05  1.21e-01   1.155096043e-01   1.090407726e-01   2.9e-04  4.54  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:42 PM: 4   1.8e-05  1.8e-05  1.7e-06  -1.12e-02  9.341400974e-02   8.411031679e-02   1.8e-05  5.02  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:42 PM: 5   9.3e-06  9.3e-06  8.8e-07  -4.30e-01  7.973164702e-02   7.085896904e-02   9.3e-06  5.26  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:42 PM: 6   6.0e-06  6.0e-06  6.1e-07  -2.58e-01  7.104737469e-02   6.077764899e-02   6.0e-06  5.51  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:43 PM: 7   9.2e-07  9.2e-07  3.9e-08  6.36e-01   2.842954592e-02   2.664187693e-02   9.2e-07  6.04  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:43 PM: 8   3.3e-07  3.3e-07  6.9e-09  3.10e-01   1.312244937e-02   1.268182239e-02   3.3e-07  6.41  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:43 PM: 9   1.6e-07  1.6e-07  2.7e-09  4.78e-01   7.677685919e-03   7.388148520e-03   1.6e-07  6.70  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:44 PM: 10  5.1e-09  5.1e-09  1.5e-11  9.99e-01   1.358048728e-03   1.349482175e-03   5.1e-09  7.22  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:44 PM: 11  4.9e-09  4.4e-09  1.5e-11  -6.94e-01  1.360571367e-03   1.349826155e-03   4.4e-09  7.50  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:44 PM: 12  4.2e-09  2.9e-09  8.0e-12  1.89e-01   1.049631511e-03   1.042161814e-03   2.9e-09  7.74  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:45 PM: 13  3.2e-09  2.1e-10  2.7e-13  4.00e-01   3.854344216e-04   3.837301023e-04   2.1e-10  8.10  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:45 PM: 14  2.2e-09  1.4e-10  1.9e-13  1.17e-01   3.601089329e-04   3.583670425e-04   1.4e-10  8.58  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: 15  6.4e-10  4.1e-11  2.7e-14  7.15e-01   2.734589867e-04   2.730397834e-04   4.1e-11  8.90  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: 16  1.3e-10  8.5e-12  3.0e-15  7.14e-01   2.505408359e-04   2.504174325e-04   8.5e-12  9.06  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: 17  2.8e-11  1.8e-12  2.9e-16  8.98e-01   2.444877868e-04   2.444619070e-04   1.8e-12  9.20  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: 18  3.6e-11  1.7e-13  8.2e-18  1.00e+00   2.431954395e-04   2.431930224e-04   1.7e-13  9.26  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: Optimizer terminated. Time: 9.32    
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: 
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: 
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: Interior-point solution summary
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM:   Problem status  : PRIMAL_AND_DUAL_FEASIBLE
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM:   Solution status : OPTIMAL
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM:   Primal.  obj: 2.4319543953e-04    nrm: 2e-01    Viol.  con: 4e-09    var: 2e-11    barvar: 0e+00  
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM:   Dual.    obj: 2.4319302238e-04    nrm: 2e+02    Viol.  con: 0e+00    var: 2e-11    barvar: 2e-11  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Summary                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: Problem status: optimal
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: Optimal value: 2.432e-04
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: Compilation took 1.436e+02 seconds
(CVXPY) Nov 09 09:30:46 PM: Solver (including time spent in interface) took 1.223e+01 seconds
Solver time: 9.324919939041138 (s)
CPU times: user 1min 34s, sys: 41.8 s, total: 2min 16s
Wall time: 2min 37
```

Thanks

Comment: Please contact Mosek support with your Fusion model. If it takes a few minutes to compile and 10 seconds to solve then something is wrong and we would like to understand and maybe be able to help. (You can also parameterize Fusion models to compile them once.)

Comment: Regarding cvxpy you can of course save the Mosek task in various formats https://docs.mosek.com/latest/faq/faq.html#cvxpy (use dump.ptf or dump.task.gz or dump.cbf) but then you must remember the problem was dualized, prerocessed etc. so it is hard to see what ends up where. That is the least recommended approach usually.

Comment: Thanks @MichalAdamaszek. Is there a possibility that cvxpy is mis-reporting time required to solve the problem? I will first compare the compile time of mosek fusion and cvxpy for the same problem before bringing it to the support.

Comment: Did you try [cvxpy's "parameter" feature](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#attributes)?

Comment: I see no reason not to trust it, it agrees with the Mosek log. Also the problem sent to Mosek seems to solve in an exemplarily nice way. It is not a huge problem either. Feel free to contact support even with the cvxpy source, we would like to see if it is something for them to look into, or maybe you can just improve the model.

Comment: I see. I haven't retried MOSEK fusion, but found a way to change parameters in cvxpy without recompiling. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To change parameter without recompiling, set the quantity as a parameter by

```
lam = cvxpy.Parameter()
...
prob = cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Minimize(...))
```

Updating its `value` before calling `prob.solve` does not trigger recompile:

```
lam.value=12334
prob.solve()
```

This is not put very clearly in the docs.